Why might transforming my features improve the performance on a simple decision tree?
The features & target in my dataset are very skewed. Could anyone explain why transforming the features & target (I'm using a Yeo-Johnson transformation) is significantly improving the performance of my model when using a decision tree?

Can you please add, which metric you use to measure "performance" and how much it differs?

This question needs a lot more detail, e.g. the code of your decision tree, and ideally some sample data that demonstrates the before/after effect you are seeing.
